# Cascading collections using NHibernate StatelessSession

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, cascade, stateless-session

What is the proper way to bulk insert entities which contain collections of other entities (a `HasMany` mapping), using stateless sessions?

E.g. Parent class is mapped like this:

```
class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
           .GeneratedBy.Increment();

        HasMany(x => x.ChildNodes)
           .KeyColumns.Add("Parent_id")
           .Cascade.All();
    }  
}
```

Stateless session ignores the Cascade option, so child nodes are not persisted automatically. I could iterate through the collection myself, but then I cannot set the relation, because `Parent_id` column does not exist as a property I could write to.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to either create the `Parent` property in the child class, or use a stateful session.